# How do I refactor the below code to allow me generate coherent and flowing document in chatGPT?

Tags: php, laravel, api, guzzle, openai-api

Am currently trying to test large text with OPENAI gpt-4 model.I am trying to refactor the below code so that the model can generate coherent,readable and flowing document.The code below does return 5000 words unfortunately it returns diffferent variations based on a topic.My expectations are that it writes one single full 5000 words document.Any help will be highly appreciated.
Check the generated document:https://docs.google.com/document/d/16zzm4w4uegng6BbNdErtaqItwGtLpHH0uEt0qLW59aE/edit?usp=sharing

The Code:

```
public function writePropmt(Request $request)
{
    $this->authCheck();
    $this->validate($request, [
        'content' => 'required',
        'maxWords' => 'required|integer|min:1',
    ]);

    ini_set('max_execution_time', 1800); // Set the maximum execution time to 10 minutes

    $content = $request->input('content');
    $maxWords = intval($request->input('maxWords'));
    $maxWordsPerRequest = 2000; // Set the maximum words to generate in each request
    $result = '';

    if (!empty($this->super_settings['openai_api_key']) && $content) {
        if ($this->isDemo() || $this->super_settings['openai_api_key'] == 'demo') {
            $result = '';
        } else {
            // Set OpenAI API Key
            $client = OpenAI::client($this->super_settings['openai_api_key']);

            try {
                $response = $client->chat()->create([
                    'model' => 'gpt-4',
                    'messages' => [
                        [
                            'role' => 'user',
                            'content' => $content,
                        ],
                    ],
                    'max_tokens' => $maxWordsPerRequest,
                ]);

                if (!empty($response->choices)) {
                    foreach ($response->choices as $data) {
                        $result .= $data->message->content;
                    }
                }

                while (strlen($result) < $maxWords && strlen($result) + $maxWordsPerRequest <= $maxWords) {
                    $response = $client->chat()->create([
                        'model' => 'gpt-4',
                        'messages' => [
                            [
                                'role' => 'user',
                                'content' => '',
                            ],
                        ],
                        'max_tokens' => $maxWordsPerRequest,
                        'prompt' => $result,
                    ]);

                    if (!empty($response->choices)) {
                        foreach ($response->choices as $data) {
                            $result .= $data->message->content;
                        }
                    }
                }

                $result = substr($result, 0, $maxWords); // Limit the result to the requested number of words
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                if ($this->user->is_super_admin) {
                    $result = 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                } else {
                    $result = __('Sorry, I am not able to write anything for you.');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (empty($result)) {
        $result = __('Sorry, I am not able to write anything for you.');
    }

    // Convert result markdown to html
    $result = Str::markdown($result);

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'result' => $result,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: 1. It appears you're expecting "words" and GPT's "tokens" to be the same thing? They aren't. This is for GPT-3, this calculator may help you understand the difference better: https://platform.openai.com/tokenizer

2. With that in mind, take a look at `tiktoken`; it might help you directly or at least directionally for how to tackle what you're trying to solve: https://github.com/openai/tiktoken

3. Re: "unfortunately it returns different variations based on a topic" -- see `temperature`, `top_p`, and `n` request body params https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create

Comment: @busse.The gpt-4 generates upto 8000 tokens.Thats about 6000 words.Unless you dont understand my question

Comment: Kevin, right, I was disambiguating tokens vs. words because in a literal sense, they are not actually the same. "coherent and flowing document" is a bit subjective. Can you clarify what the expected output is in an objective way? Is it that you only want, for example, the first response shown in the Google Doc without also getting the additional responses? Explicitly, what is wrong with the output you're getting that you're looking to correct?

Comment: If you look at the document I shared in that link, the number of words is per the expectations.The problem is that it variates the context(Variation here means it writes the same topic under different versions to fill the document).My expectation is that it spins a single document based on the title that meets the 5000+words.

Answer (score 0):

In your question and clarifying comments, you state that you are looking for a single 5,000-word (token) response.

The reason you are getting successive responses is because you have set `$maxWordsPerRequest = 2000;` and then after the first request, the script is written to send multiple separate requests, and append them into a single string until you get to the `$maxWords` value that is being passed into the code shown.

That happens in this part of your code; this entire `while` statement should be removed from your script:

```
while (strlen($result) < $maxWords && strlen($result) + $maxWordsPerRequest <= $maxWords) {
                    $response = $client->chat()->create([
                        'model' => 'gpt-4',
                        'messages' => [
                            [
                                'role' => 'user',
                                'content' => '',
                            ],
                        ],
                        'max_tokens' => $maxWordsPerRequest,
                        'prompt' => $result,
                    ]);

                    if (!empty($response->choices)) {
                        foreach ($response->choices as $data) {
                            $result .= $data->message->content;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Additionally, immediately before that section in the part where you first call sent a request and get a response, you also have a `foreach` to check for multiple response choices and append them together:

```
                if (!empty($response->choices)) {
                    foreach ($response->choices as $data) {
                        $result .= $data->message->content;
                    }
                }
```

You should only be getting one response choice since that is the default `n` value for the model and you aren't requesting `n` > 1, however, that `foreach` could potentially allow additional response choices to slip through if the model returns multiple choices.

**To achieve the desired result, be sure to set:**

`$maxWordsPerRequest = 5000;`